# Laziness/strictness between data and newtype

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, algebraic-data-types, newtype

I'm struggling to understand why these two snippets produce different results under the so-called "poor man's strictness analysis".

The first example uses `data` (assuming a correct Applicative instance):

```
data Parser t a = Parser {
        getParser ::  [t] -> Maybe ([t], a) 
    }

> getParser (pure (,) <*> literal ';' <*> undefined ) "abc"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

The second uses `newtype`.  There is no other difference:

```
newtype Parser t a = Parser {
        getParser ::  [t] -> Maybe ([t], a) 
    }

> getParser (pure (,) <*> literal ';' <*> undefined ) "abc"
Nothing
```

`literal x` is a parser that succeeds consuming one token of input if its argument matches the first token.  So in this example, it fails since `;` doesn't match `a`.  However, the `data` example still sees that the next parser is undefined, while the `newtype` example doesn't.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649305/why-is-there-data-and-newtype-in-haskell), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889696/difference-between-data-and-newtype-in-haskell), and [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype#The_messy_bits), but don't understand them well enough to get why the first example is undefined.  It seems to me that in this example, `newtype` is *more* lazy than `data`, the opposite of what the answers said.  (At least [one other person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649305/why-is-there-data-and-newtype-in-haskell#comment18152293_2650051) has been confused by this too).

**Why does switching from `data` to `newtype` change the definedness of this example?**

---

Here's another thing I discovered:  with this Applicative instance, the `data` parser above outputs undefined:

```
instance Applicative (Parser s) where
  Parser f <*> Parser x = Parser h
    where
      h xs = 
        f xs >>= \(ys, f') -> 
        x ys >>= \(zs, x') ->
        Just (zs, f' x')

  pure a = Parser (\xs -> Just (xs, a))
```

whereas with this instance, the `data` parser above does *not* output undefined (assuming a correct Monad instance for `Parser s`):

```
instance Applicative (Parser s) where
  f <*> x =
      f >>= \f' ->
      x >>= \x' ->
      pure (f' x')

  pure = pure a = Parser (\xs -> Just (xs, a))
```

---

Full code snippet:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (liftM)

data Parser t a = Parser {
        getParser ::  [t] -> Maybe ([t], a) 
    }


instance Functor (Parser s) where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative (Parser s) where
  Parser f <*> Parser x = Parser h
    where
      h xs = f xs >>= \(ys, f') -> 
        x ys >>= \(zs, x') ->
        Just (zs, f' x')

  pure = return


instance Monad (Parser s) where
  Parser m >>= f = Parser h
    where
      h xs =
          m xs >>= \(ys,y) ->
          getParser (f y) ys

  return a = Parser (\xs -> Just (xs, a))


literal :: Eq t => t -> Parser t t
literal x = Parser f
  where
    f (y:ys)
      | x == y = Just (ys, x)
      | otherwise = Nothing
    f [] = Nothing
```

Comment: When asking a question like this, it's generally better if you include all the relevant code, if it's small enough to fit (this includes the `Functor` and `Monad` instances, and `literal`), so that people don't have to guess at exactly how you wrote the functions (as you've pointed out, even small changes can make a difference in behavior).

Comment: @shachaf the real question here is not "how do I fix my code?" -- I already did that -- but "what is different between `data` and `newtype` with respect to strictness/laziness?"  Sorry if that's not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes, but even so, how can we explain what was going on with your code without knowing what the code looks like?

Comment: Presumably the behaviour with the Applicative instances comes from (in the first example) the fact that pattern matching is strict, i.e. both `Parser f` and `Parser x` are forced. (E.g `f (Just x) (Just y) = x; f (Just 1) undefined` throws an exception.)

Comment: @shachaf hopefully it will help; I'm still hoping to understand this issue in a broader context than just how it applies to this specific problem though.

Comment: [This article](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/12/gin-and-monotonic/) explains the difference using Hasse diagrams, and shows the difference between lazy data, strict data, and newtype.

Comment: I wrote a Haskellwiki article on [newtype](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype) which explains some of the issues.

Comment: I had not run into this issue; but I think that I learned something useful from the explanations here.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you probably know, the main difference between `data` and `newtype` is that with `data` the data constructors are lazy while with `newtype` the data constructors are strict, i.e. given the following types

```
data    D a = D a 
newtype N a = N a
```

then `` D ⊥ `seq` x = x ``, but `` N ⊥ `seq` x = ⊥ ``.<sup>(where `⊥` stands for "bottom", i.e. undefined value or error)</sup>

What is perhaps less commonly known, however, is that *when you pattern match* on these data constructors,
the roles are *"reversed"*, i.e. with

```
constD x (D y) = x
constN x (N y) = x
```

then `constD x ⊥ = ⊥` (strict), but `constN x ⊥ = x` (lazy).

This is what's happening in your example.

```
Parser f <*> Parser x = Parser h where ...
```

With `data`, the pattern match in the definition of `<*>` will diverge immediately if either
of the arguments are `⊥`, but with `newtype` the constructors are ignored and it is
just as if you'd written

```
f <*> x = h where
```

which will only diverge for `x = ⊥` if `x` is demanded.

Comment: Two things I'm still not quite clear on are 1) whether the pattern matching difference is necessitated by Haskell's semantics, and 2) whether the pattern matching difference is due to the constructor's strictness difference.

Comment: @MattFenwick: 1) Yes, since newtypes basically don't exist semantically, pattern matching on one is the same as pattern matching on the underlying type, so since the pattern `x` doesn't evaluate `x`, neither does the pattern `N x`. 2) No. Consider `data S a = S !a; constS x (S y) = x`, then ```S undefined `seq` x = ⊥```, and `constS x ⊥ = ⊥`.

Comment: So in the case of a data constructor the compiler has to evaluate far enough to determine whether the constructor matches the pattern?

Comment: @JesseHallett: Yes, even when there's only one constructor.

Answer (score 11):

The difference between `data` and `newtype` is that `data` is "lifted" and `newtype` isn't. That means the `data` has an extra ⊥ -- in this case, it means that `undefined` /= `Parser undefined`. When your `Applicative` code pattern-matches on `Parser x`, it forces a `⊥` value if the constructor.

When you pattern-match on a `data` constructor, it's evaluated and taken apart to make sure it's not ⊥. For example:

```
λ> data Foo = Foo Int deriving Show
λ> case undefined of Foo _ -> True
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So pattern matching on a `data` constructor is strict, and will force it. A `newtype`, on the other hand, is represented in exactly the same way as the type its constructor wraps. So matching on a `newtype` constructor does absolutely nothing:

```
λ> newtype Foo = Foo Int deriving Show
λ> case undefined of Foo _ -> True
True
```

There are probably two ways to change your `data` program such that it doesn't crash. One would be to use an irrefutable pattern match in your `Applicative` instance, which will always "succeed" (but using the matched values anywhere later might fail). Every `newtype` match behaves like an irrefutable pattern (since there's no constructor to match on, strictness-wise).

```
λ> data Foo = Foo Int deriving Show
λ> case undefined of ~(Foo _) -> True
True
```

The other would be to use `Parser undefined` instead of `undefined`:

```
λ> case Foo undefined of Foo _ -> True
True
```

This match will succeed, because there *is* a valid `Foo` value that's being matched on. It happens to contained `undefined`, but that's not relevant since we don't use it -- we only look at the topmost constructor.

---

In addition to all the links you gave, you might find [this article](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/12/hussling-haskell-types-into-hasse-diagrams/) relevant.