# Difference between `newtype` and `data` with a strictness annotation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, newtype

How does this code

```
data D = D { _d :: ![P] } -- Note the strictness annotation!
```

Compare to this

```
newtype D = D { _d :: [P] }
```

An [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567709/40916) says:

> the main difference between data and newtype is that with data is that data constructors are lazy while newtype is strict

How does this difference work when the `data` version has a strictness annotation?

(the question is based on real code the I've stumbled on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For instance,

```
case undefined of
   D d -> "hello"
```

will error out for `data` types (strict or not strict), but will evaluate to `"hello"` for newtypes.

This is because, at runtime, applying a `newtype` constructor, or pattern matching on it corresponds to no operation. Not even forcing the value we `case` upon.

By contrast, pattern matching on a `data` constructor always forces the value we `case` upon.

I think this is the only runtime difference between strict `data` and `newtype`.
There are some static differences, such as some GHC extensions which only affect `newtype`, `Coercible`, etc., but at runtime the two types are isomorphic (but pattern matching operates differently, as shown above).

Comment: So if no such pattern matching is done, there's absolutely no difference between the two?

Comment: There should be a slight memory overhead with the strict data that isn't there with the newtype, but I don't remember if GHC can optimize that out.

Comment: @yairchu I think so. There's a small memory overhead with strict data, as DarthFennec points out. Note that "if no such pattern matching" can be a big "if" -- pattern matching is everything for data types. E.g. `case expensiveFunction 23 of D d -> ...` performs the expensive computation immediately for big data, potentially keeping in memory a long list `d` for a long time depending on the `...`. With a newtype, that list would be bound lazily, and only generated afterwards, when (and if) demanded by the `...`.