# Why do I have to use newtype when my data type declaration only has one constructor?

Tags: haskell, ghc

In other words, if I have a declaration like

```
data Identity a = Identity a
```

why can't GHC see that I only have one constructor and pretend that it is seeing `newtype` instead of `data`?

Comment: You don't **have** to use `newtype` at all. You just don't get the convenience that `newtype` gives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2650051/509936