# Why `data` cause an infinite loop while `newtype` not

Tags: haskell, arrows, newtype

I am learning `Arrow` following the tutorial [programming with arrows](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf). I've typed the following code according to the paper except that the `SF` is defined by `data`, not by `newtype` as in the paper (*actually, I made this change by chance, since I typed the code from memory*):

```
import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))

data SF a b = SF { runSF :: [a] -> [b] }  -- this is the change, using data instead of newtype as in the paper 

-- The folowing code is the same as in the paper
instance Category SF where
  id = SF $ \x -> x
  (SF f) . (SF g) = SF $ \x -> f (g x)

instance Arrow SF where
  arr f = SF $ map f
  first (SF f) = SF $ unzip >>> first f >>> uncurry zip

instance ArrowChoice SF where
  left (SF f) = SF $ \xs -> combine xs (f [y | Left y <- xs])
    where
      combine (Left _ : ys) (z:zs) = Left z : combine ys zs
      combine (Right y : ys) zs = Right y : combine ys zs
      combine [] _ = []

delay :: a -> SF a a
delay x = SF $ init . (x:)

mapA :: ArrowChoice a => a b c -> a [b] [c]
mapA f = arr listcase >>>
         arr (const []) ||| (f *** mapA f >>> arr (uncurry (:)))

listcase :: [a] -> Either () (a, [a])
listcase [] = Left ()
listcase (x:xs) = Right (x, xs)
```

When I load the file in `ghci` and execute `runSF (mapA (delay 0)) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, it triggers an infinit loop and runs out of memory finally. If I change `data` back to `newtype`, everything is OK. The same problem happens in ghc 8.0.2, 8.2.2 and 8.6.3.

The same problem also exists even I compile the code into an executable.

I have thought the difference between `data` and `newtype`, when defining a data structure with only one field, is the runtime cost. But this problem seems to imply more difference between them. Or there may be something that I haven't noticed about the `Arrow` type-class.

Can anyone have any ideas? Thanks very much!

Comment: I think it'll have something to do with data giving a lazy value constructor, newtype being strict. See for example Rose's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649305/why-is-there-data-and-newtype-in-haskell . Perhaps someone more familiar could work through the code and give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at this example.

```
data A = A [Int]
    deriving (Show)

cons :: Int -> A -> A
cons x (A xs) = A (x:xs)

ones :: A
ones = cons 1 ones
```

We would expect that `ones` should be `A [1,1,1,1...]`, because all we have done is wrap a list in a `data` constructor.  But we would be wrong.  Recall that *pattern matches are strict* for `data` constructors.  That is, `cons 1 undefined = undefined` rather than `A (1 : undefined)`.  So when we try to evaluate `ones`, `cons` pattern matches on its second argument, which causes us to evaluate `ones`... we have a problem.

`newtype`s don't do this.  At runtime `newtype` constructors are invisible, so it's as if we had written the equivalent program on plain lists

```
cons :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
cons x ys = x:ys

ones = cons 1 ones
```

which is perfectly productive, since when we try to evaluate `ones`, there is a `:` constructor between us and the next evaluation of `ones`.

You can get back the `newtype` semantics by making your data constructor pattern matches lazy:

```
cons x ~(A xs) = A (x:xs)
```

This is the problem with your code (I have run into this exact problem doing this exact thing).  There are a few reasons `data` pattern matches are strict by default; the most compelling one I see is that pattern matching would otherwise be impossible if the type had more than one constructor. There is also a small runtime overhead to lazy pattern matching in order to fix some subtle GC leaks; details linked in the comments.

Comment: You're probably talking about http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/garbage-collection.html

Comment: Yes, that’s problem with lazy match.  The solution was invented before Phil’s paper, but not published.

Comment: @augustss, are you sure GHC uses that later approach? I'm pretty sure it doesn't, for some performance reason or other. There is a special "selector thunk" heap object type that the garbage collector handles specially.

Comment: No, I’m not sure.  I think the non-gc method is better, but maybe ghc didn’t use it in the end.