# Why does recursive binding of arrow function in Haskell loop infinitely?

Tags: haskell, recursion, infinite-loop, arrows, interpretation

I'm learning how to use Arrows in Haskell by implementing a simple interpreter for the [comm](https://plzoo.andrej.com/language/comm.html) language.

I have an eval function which evaluates an expression into a value, but eval loops indefinitely when feeding in any expression.

```
-- Interp.hs

eval :: A Expr Val
eval = proc e -> case e of
    Lit x -> returnA -< Num x
    Var s -> do
        lookup -< s
    Add e1 e2 -> do
        v1 <- eval -< e1
        v2 <- eval -< e2
        case (v1, v2) of
            (Num x, Num y) -> returnA -< Num (x + y)
```

Executing this in GHCI results in an infinite loop

```
*Interp> unpack eval M.empty (Lit 1)
```

Commenting out the eval's in the case of the Add expression does result in the expression giving a result

e.g.

```
-- Interp.hs

eval :: A Expr Val
eval = proc e -> case e of
    Lit x -> returnA -< Num x
    Var s -> do
        lookup -< s
    Add e1 e2 -> do
        returnA -< Num 1
--        v1 <- eval -< e1
--        v2 <- eval -< e2
--        case (v1, v2) of
--            (Num x, Num y) -> returnA -< Num (x + y)
```

```
*Interp> unpack eval M.empty (Lit 1)
(Right (Num 1),fromList [])
```

Here's the code in question
The arrow used is a sort of state function that keeps passing context after failure.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module Interp where

import Prelude hiding (lookup, fail)

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category

data Expr
    = Lit Int
    | Var String
    | Add Expr Expr
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Val
    = Num Int
    deriving (Show, Eq)

type Env = M.Map String Val

data A b c = A { unpack :: (Env -> b -> (Either String c, Env)) }

instance Category A where
    id = A (\env b -> (Right b, env))
    A g . A f = A $ \env b -> case f env b of
        (Left err, env') -> (Left err, env')
        (Right c, env') -> g env' c

instance Arrow A where
    arr f = A $ \env b -> (Right (f b), env)
    first (A f) = A $ \env (b, d) -> case f env b of
        (Left err, env') -> (Left err, env')
        (Right c, env') -> (Right (c, d), env')

instance ArrowChoice A where
    left (A f) = A $ \env e -> case e of
        Left b -> case f env b of
            (Left err, env') -> (Left err, env')
            (Right c, env') -> (Right (Left c), env')
        Right d -> (Right (Right d), env)

lookup :: A String Val
lookup = A $ \env k -> case M.lookup k env of
    Nothing -> (Left "Variable not bound", env)
    Just v -> (Right v, env)

eval :: A Expr Val
eval = proc e -> case e of
    Lit x -> returnA -< Num x
    Var s -> do
        lookup -< s
    Add e1 e2 -> do
        v1 <- eval -< e1
        v2 <- eval -< e2
        case (v1, v2) of
            (Num x, Num y) -> returnA -< Num (x + y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can fix the non-termination:

1. Change `A` from a `data` declaration to a `newtype` declaration.
2. Change the pattern matching in the definitions of `first` and `left` to be lazy, i.e.:

   ```
   first ~(A f) = A $ ...same as before...
   left ~(A f) = A $ ...same as before...
   ```

Both of these fixes address the same root issue. From [another StackOverflow answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21081227/8201661)

> [With `data` declarations], when pattern matching against value constructors, [thunks] WILL be evaluated at least to weak head normal form (WHNF). [...] [With `newtype` declarations,] when pattern matching against value constructors, [thunks] WILL NOT be evaluated at all.

To continue, I will explain a major difference between `newtype` and `data` declarations, and then I will explain how it applies to your case.

### Strictness properties of `newtype` and `data`

Most of the following is paraphrased and adapted from [the HaskellWiki article on the same topic](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype).

`newtype` is intended to introduce a type that is exactly isomorphic to an existing type. Given a declaration `newtype T1 = T1 { unpack :: Int }`, we would like `unpack . T1` and `id` to be equal at the type `Int -> Int`, and likewise for `T1 . unpack` and `id` to be equal at the type `T1 -> T1`.

But why does this not already hold for `data T2 = T2 { unpack :: Int }`; that is, why is `T2 . unpack` not the same as `id`? The reason is non-termination. `T2 (unpack _|_)` evaluates to `T2 _|_`, but `id _|_` evaluates to `_|_` (where I'm using `_|_` to stand for the non-terminating computation "bottom", as is customary). We can distiguish `_|_` and `T2 _|_` with the following expression:

`\x -> case x of T2 _ -> ()`

Applying this lambda to `_|_` yields `_|_`, but applying this lambda to `T2 _|_` yields `()`. That is, because the constructor `T2` can possibly hold a non-terminating value, the language makes it possible to distinguish `_|_` and `T2 _|_`.

The `newtype` declaration gives us a perhaps surprising property: `T1 (unpack _|_)` evaluates to `_|_`, but `case _|_ of T1 _ -> ()` evaluates to `()`! That is, because `T1 _|_` is not intended to be distinguishable from `_|_`, the language does not force evaluation of values of type `T1` when pattern matching against the `T1` value constructor. And, as we'll see shortly, this property is important with recursive definitions.

### Lazy patterns

There is a way to recover a newtype-like behavior for `data` declarations: use lazy pattern matching. Given a function like:

```
f x = case x of ~(T2 y) -> \() -> y
```

you will find that both `f (T2 _|_)` and `f _|_` evaluate to a value (i.e., a function of type `Unit -> Int` that would diverge as soon as it is applied to an argument). This is because the lazy pattern match is identical to the function:

```
f = \x -> case x of t -> \() -> unpack t
```

and so the evaluation of the thunk passed as `x` is "deferred" in the sense that it is only evaluated when `unpack t` is evaluated, in the body of the lambda `\() -> unpack t`.

### Newtype vs. data declarations for your example

I will now desugar the arrow notation in your example and then identify the source of the non-termination.

To desugar the arrow notation, I used the [`arrowp` program](https://github.com/pepeiborra/arrowp). This is what it yields on your program:

```
$ arrowp-ext interp.hs
eval :: A Expr Val
eval
       = (arr
       (\ e ->
          case e of
              Lit x -> (Left) (x)
              Var s -> (Right) ((Left) (s))
              Add e1 e2 -> (Right) ((Right) ((e1, e2))))
       >>>
       (((arr (\ x -> Num x)) >>> (returnA)) |||
          (((arr (\ s -> s)) >>> (lookup)) |||
             (((first ((arr (\ e1 -> e1)) >>> (eval))) >>>
                 (arr (\ (v1, e2) -> (e2, v1))))
                >>>
                (first ((arr (\ e2 -> e2)) >>> (eval))) >>>
                  (arr
                     (\ (v2, v1) ->
                        case
                          case (v1, v2) of
                              (Num x, Num y) -> (x, y)
                          of
                            (x, y) -> Num (x + y)))
                    >>> (returnA)))))
```

You identified that `eval` doesn't terminate when applied to an argument, but the problem is more serious than that: `eval` diverges, period. This can be observed in ghci:

```
*Interp> eval `seq` 0
```

The proximal cause of the non-termination is the expression `first ((arr (\ e1 -> e1)) >>> (eval))`, which is the same as `first eval`. The first parameter in the definition of `first` involves a strict pattern match against a value constructor (`first (A f)`), and `A` originates from a data declaration, and so, re-quoting [@wonder.mice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506566/wonder-mice):

> [With data declarations], when pattern matching against value constructors, [thunks] WILL be evaluated at least to weak head normal form (WHNF).

When the expression `first eval` is encountered in the definition of `eval`, the thunk for `eval` has not yet been evaluated to WHNF, and so when `first eval` attempts to evaluate its argument to WHNF, it will not terminate.

One way to fix this is to change `A` to a `newtype` declaration. ("1. Change `A` from a `data` declaration to a `newtype` declaration.") Then,

> ...when pattern matching against value constructors, [thunks] WILL NOT be evaluated at all.

The other way to fix this is to make `first` use a lazy pattern match instead of a strict one ("2. Change the pattern matching in the definitions of `first` and `left` to be lazy"). This will have the net effect of making the pattern match behave the same as for a newtype declaration, where "thunks WILL NOT be evaluated at all".

A similar explanation can be used for why `|||` is not behaving in a lazy manner for your example, even though it does for e.g. the Arrow instance for `(->)`. Changing `left` to use a lazy pattern match will take care of this issue, or just using a `newtype` declaration will be sufficient.

Comment: IOW, *use `newtype A ...` instead of `data A ...`* (?) .

Comment: @Will Oh, I didn't realize that was relevant here. It might be good to add your own answer if it's simpler.

Comment: it's just a guess... feel free to edit it in, if it works. :) --- I'm having a bit of trouble parsing your "The lazy pattern defers the forcing to under the body of the lambda in your definition of first.", maybe you could copy-edit for clarity?

Comment: I tried to clarify, and I incorporated your suggestion regarding `newtype`

Comment: thanks; nice answer! --- so maybe the central point is that we had there `first (arr id >>> eval)` and this must be equivalent to `first (id >>> eval)` and that must be equivalent to just `first eval`; but it wasn't.